# Is a discount reported as income?

Tags: united-states, income, services

I will owe $600 to my child's private school (run by a non profit).  I have agreed to teach one of the classes, so instead of paying my bill, I would rather have them deduct what I owe from my paycheck.  Is the deduction income?  If so, where would I declare it?

Comment: I randomly guessed a country for you, please correct me if it is wrong.

Comment: I'm a little confused about your question. Is the $600 amount a discounted price? If so, are you asking about whether the amount of the discount is taxable?

Comment: How is this a discount? You will work for them and earn money. You also happen to owe them $600, which you say they'll deduct from your pay. I don't see a discount.

Answer (score 2):

On your paycheck stub you can see deductions from  your gross pay.

- Some are taxes: Federal income tax, state income tax, Social Security...
- Some are pre-tax: 401K, Health Insurance, Flexible Spending account, Commuting...
- Some are post-tax:  Roth 401K, Supplemental Insurance, coffee fund...

Pretax deductions reduce your taxable income in the eyes of the IRS.

The 600 in tuition that they pull from your gross pay would not reduce your taxable income.

If they waive the $600 in tuition and don't pull it from your paycheck they will count that $600 as income. It will appear on the part of the paycheck that describes your gross income.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the deduction is income. It will be reported as your salary and deducted after-tax.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where there's a "discount" here. You're just saying they'd deduct something from your paycheck. In that case, the W-2 they send you next year will show the total they paid, before this deduction. You wouldn't have to do anything special to report it, just report your income as it appears on the W-2.

If they really give you a discount, if they said that because you work for the school (it appears from your post that this is the case), they will give you a discount on tuition, like regular tuition is $2000 but employees of the school only pay $1000, I don't think this discount would be taxable. If a store advertises "Memorial Day Sale! Everything 25% off!", you don't owe taxes on the difference between the regular price and the sale price. But in some cases employee benefits are considered taxable income. To the best of my knowledge, this is only when the company pays some third party for a service on your behalf, like once I worked for a company that would pay for employee gym or YMCA memberships, and what they paid was taxable income. (But please don't take that sentence as definitive. As it's not the main point of the question I haven't researched it and I certainly don't claim to have the entire tax code in my head.) The employer should report any taxable benefits on your W-2, but if you're worried about it or it's a complicated case, check with a tax lawyer.

*Update*

Okay, I just did a little research. The taxability of employee benefits is described in IRS publication 15-B, http://www.irs.gov/publications/p15b/ar02.html#en_US_2014_publink1000193672. The basic rule is that all fringe benefits are considered taxable income EXCEPT for those that are specifically listed as non-taxable or partially taxable. The list of exclusions is pretty long, and includes most of the common fringe benefits, like employer contributions to health insurance and retirement plans.

For employee discounts, the rule is: For services, the first 20% of what you charge non-employees. i.e. if the regular price is $100, and you offer this service to employees for $80, the discount is not taxable. Any discount past that first 20% is taxable. For products, the rule is: multiply your gross profit by the regular sale price to non-employees, and this amount is not taxable. Basically what littleadv said, except my reading of the rules is that you have to base the profit percentage on sales of all products, not this particular product. A discount is not taxable if it does not cost the company anything to provide. For example, if an airline allows employees to fly for free or at a discount when there are unsold seats on the plane, this costs the airline little or nothing, and so is not taxable.

Comment: Employee discount below the production/acquisition cost is taxable.

Comment: @Jay - what discount? She owes money, and is working it off. If you remove "I would rather have them deduct what I owe from my paycheck" and she simply gets paid, cashes the check (at one of our check cashing stores) and pays off the $600, there's no issue. She never said the school gives her a discount because she works there. And littleadv's note is correct, but only if there were a discount.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Please read the first sentence of my post. :-)